# The structure of a sentence in "A Living and a Dead Faith" by William Cowper

Tags: sentence-meaning, coordination, poetry

From "[A Living and a Dead Faith](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Poetical_Works_of_William_Cowper_(Benham)/Olney_Hymns#LX._A_LIVING_AND_A_DEAD_FAITH)" by William Cowper (part of the "[Olney Hymns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olney_Hymns)"):

> With golden bells, the priestly vest,
>   And rich pomegranates border'd round,
>   The need of holiness expressed,
>   And called for fruit as well as sound.

There are no finite verbs in the sentence. I presume that there is an omission of the verb **is** before "expressed":

> With golden bells, the priestly vest,
>   And rich pomegranates border'd round,
>   The need of holiness **is** expressed,
>   And called for fruit as well as sound.

But then I cannot account for "called". I cannot imagine the verb **is** before "called". If I put **is** before "called", I get

> The need of holiness **is** called for fruit as well as sound.

This does not seem to work.

So we seemingly have the non-finite verb "called" unattached to any finite verb.

Is this an example of poetic license, with a non-finite verb "hanging in the air" ungrammatically? Or am I missing something?

I understand the general meaning of the stanza, but the parts of the sentence do not seem to dovetail together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two finite verbs in this stanza, *expressed* and *called*; their subject is *the priestly vest* (*vest* for *vestment*, 'robe' in the Authorized Version)— see Ex 28:33-34

> And beneath upon the hem of it thou shalt make pomegranates of blue, and of purple, and of scarlet, round about the hem thereof; and bells of gold between them round about: a golden bell and a pomegranate, a golden bell and a pomegranate, upon the hem of the robe round about.

In Cowper's interpretation, this vest, bordered around with pomegranates and bells, expressed the need for holiness but also demanded the 'fruit' of holiness, explained in the next stanza as *faith and love*.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a list of things! I thought "golden bells" were church bells that look golden. It would have been more understandable if the verbs were "expresses" and "calls". Because logically it still expresses that with its golden bells and pomegranates.

Comment: @CopperKettle It's past tense because he's speaking of past *sacra*. The office of high priest disappeared when the Temple was destroyed, and his vestments disappeared too. So did the Ark, until Indiana Jones found it and stored it in a warehouse in Arizona.

Comment: Ah, it's "[High Priest of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Priest_of_Israel)". I would never have guessed.